# roscore using Java swing

Tags: java

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I wanna run roscore from my java swing class and i keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/bin/roscore", line 62, in <module>
       import roslaunch
ImportError: No module named roslaunch
```

although when i run it from the terminal it works fine.

thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209167/roscore-using-java-swing/) by [maha](https://answers.ros.org/users/21965/maha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2015-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most likely you have not setup your environment correctly. The Java program could be using a 'clean' shell to execute your command, while in your shell you've sourced the relevant `setup.bash`.

I'm not sure whether it is enough to run the Java program from a shell in which you've sourced `setup.bash` or if you need to configure the methods you use to invoke `roscore` in such a way that the embedded shell is configured correctly. I'll leave that for you.

---

Edit:

> I'm sorry... is there anything that u suggest I could do to fix the problem? if there's any.. could you please be specific with the steps? I cannot understand what u r saying.

This is all rather unrelated to ROS, but: for `java.lang.ProcessBuilder` the following can be found in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html):

> This class is used to create operating system processes.

> [..]

> Each process builder manages these process attributes:

> [..]

> - an environment, which is a system-dependent mapping from variables to values. The initial value is a copy of the environment of the current process (see [System.getenv()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv())).

So it would appear that at least `ProcessBuilder` will pass on the entire environment of the shell the Java program was started in to the shell that is used to start your `roscore` in. That means that it should be sufficient to start your program in a shell where you've already done `source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash`, and everything "should work".

In case of Eclipse, starting it **from the shell (terminal window) where you sourced `setup.bash`** should also work. You can do that using `/path/to/eclipse/installation/eclipse`.

If you cannot do that (because of deployment or whatever), you can use `ProcessBuilder`'s methods to setup the required environment variables first, and then start `roscore`. This is documented at the end of the intro in the documentation of `ProcessBuilder`:

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
 Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
 env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
 env.remove("OTHERVAR");
 env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
 pb.directory(new File("myDir"));
 Process p = pb.start();
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maha](https://answers.ros.org/users/21965/maha/) on 2015-05-14**:
can you explain how can I run my java program from a shell? I'm using eclipse.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-05-14**:
Run Eclipse from a properly setup shell? The one you sourced `setup.bash` in? But that will still not guarantee that that shell's environment will be passed on to the one Java uses to start `roscore` in.

**Comment by [maha](https://answers.ros.org/users/21965/maha/) on 2015-05-14**:
I'm sorry... is there anything that u suggest I could do to fix the problem? if there's any.. could you please be specific with the steps? I cannot understand what u r saying.